# Jquery Datatable filter duplicate rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cbEfqLwFaq?indent=2';

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'paging': false,
    'bFilter': false,
    'ajax': {
      type: 'POST',
      'url': url,
      'data': function (d) {
        return JSON.stringify( d );
      }
    }
  });
  table.column( 3 ).data().unique();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I am trying to use [datatable unique function](https://datatables.net/reference/api/unique()) but I am unable to execute it. Actually I want to remove the duplicate data I am using dynamic ajax data.

```
table
    .column( 3 )
    .data()
    .unique();
```

Like in this example I want to filter out the cities, Kindly suggest me what I am doing wrong and is there any other way, I couldnt found any other answers in stackoverflow or may be unable to understand. I am using version 1.10.9

Comment: Please create a snippet instead of simple providing a fiddle link - you really  should not expect users to leave SO to investigate

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Added

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas nO ERORR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take notice of the actual purpose of `unique` :

> Create a **new API instance** containing only the unique items from a the
>   elements in an instance's result set.

Unique *returns* a filtered set of unique items, it does not filter the rows shown in the table. Since you want to show rows where duplicated data is removed I will suggest you filter out the duplicates in the `dataSrc` callback. You do not provide details about the JSON, but here is an example with one of the "canonical" JSON datasets, where duplicated offices is filtered out. It simply uses javascripts `Array.filter` on the returned `data` array :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/avxod',
    dataSrc: function(json) {
       var offices = [];
       return json.data.filter(function(item) {
         if (!~offices.indexOf(item.office)) {
           offices.push(item.office);
           return item;
         }
       })
    }
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'position' },    
    { data: 'office' },        
    { data: 'salary' }
  ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cbcqdj7h/**

Comment: Thanks I will implement then mark as an answer if its working on my environment.

Comment: This works! Although the results are filtered, the total records are still showing up as a higher number due to duplicates. How would you modify the result set total count?

Comment: @KathirSidVel Are you using `serverSide` ...? See this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426357/datatable-dont-create-certain-rows and follow the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `unique` there just return nothing.

If you just want get a unique data after you get real data.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ...,
    drawCallback:function(){
        var a = table.column( 3 ).data().unique();
        console.log(a);
    }
})
```

If you want filter data without the same value.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'paging': false,
    'bFilter': false,
    'ajax': {
      type: 'POST',
      'url': url,
      'data': function (d) {
        // TODO do some thing here to filter value
        return JSON.stringify( d );
      }
    }
  });
```

And DataTable doc https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax