# Datatable don't create certain rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

There is a callback to not create specific rows ?

Here is my datatable object :

```
 $('#table').DataTable({
    dom: "t<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>",
    autoWidth: false,
    serverSide: true,
    aaSorting: [[8, 'desc']],
    beforeCreatedRow: function(row, data) {
        if ( data.field == "OFF" ) {
            // DON'T CREATE THIS ROW
        }
    },
    rowId: 'id',
    lengthChange: false,
    iDisplayLength: 10,
    columns: [
        {data: "column1"},
        {data: "column2"},
        {data: "column3"},
        {data: "column4"},
        {data: "column5"},
        {data: "column6"}
    ]
});
```

I used `beforeCreatedRow` event just for the example. I'm not sure this event exist. It's just to show you what I need.

So as you can see I need to not create the row if `data.field` value is OFF

Comment: If you're loading the data from the server, remove it from the response there.

Comment: This is not working code. How do you retrieve the data?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would like to remove all rows from the server but I can't. That is why I ask this question to do it client side. I have an adapter and I just have to send the sql view. But I'll not talk about this here it's not the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not populate the DOM with useless rows. Instead of hiding them, simply skip them :

```
ajax: {
  url: 'some/url/',
  dataSrc: function(d) {
    var data = d.filter(function(row) {
      if (row.field != "OFF") return row
    })
    return data
  }
}
```

---

You can remove not needed rows *prior* to `dataSrc` by hooking into the [`xhr.dt`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event :

```
$('#example').on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, json, xhr ) {
  json.data = json.data.filter(function(row) {
     if (row.field != 'OFF') return row
  })
})
```

see a demo here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/g4h7950t/**

Note: The example above is using a `{ data: [..] }` src. Was simply what I had on hand.

Comment: Yep that's the best way and this is what I want to do. But I'm already use dataSrc to do something so I'm trying to implement your code in my current function

Comment: It returns an array of undefined  with jsut 1 result :/. I think there is an incompatibility with the server side.

Comment: @John See update, you can intercept the data even before `dataSrc` andby that  process before. Yeah, the first code was pseudo, was asking for how you retrieve the src but got no response.   You need to iterate over `data` if you have a `{ data: [...] }` format, otherwise the result itself. And use `filter` instead of `map`...

Comment: Yep I understand your answer works very well. But there is a big problem because I load data 10 by 10. So datatable need 10 data in any cases. If we remove 8 data I have just 2 data in the array object but GUI needs 10 row. If I'm using your way we need add another server side call to populate the array. So the only way is to do that server side... But I can't because I have to edit the framework adapter :(

Comment: @John, You can update `json.recordsTotal` according to how many rows you have filtered out.  Try console out the content of `json`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowCallback` method something like this

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
   "rowCallback": function(row, data, index){
      if ( row.field == "OFF" ) {
         jQuery(row).hide();
      }
   }
});
```

More detail [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback)

Comment: It works thanks. But instead of `row.field` I have to use `data.field`. There is a way to not create the row ? Because here we just hide the row and it will be strange if I'm using filter column because there is a result without visible row. I tried to do `jQuery(row).remove();` but it doesn't work